# Grid items who take up the available horizontal space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid containing 16 grid items.

I want the top row to take 4 grid items, second row 3, third row 2 and fourth row 7. I want each of them to be evenly spaced so that they take up all the available space.

I can to an extent achieve this by specifying a number in `grid-template-columns`, i.e. 12, and using `grid-column-end: span-*` on grid items. However this is not adequate for the row in which I want 7 items spaced evenly.

**expected behaviour using `grid-column-end` on grid items (apart from the final row with 7 items, whose last item forces itself into a row not specified in `grid-template-columns`):**
[image]

Code snippet of above:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr [col]);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 50px [row]);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tier1 {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.tier2 {
  background-color: mediumorchid;
  grid-column-end: span 4;
}

.tier3 {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  grid-column-end: span 6;
}

.tier4 {
  background-color: mediumvioletred;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item tier1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier3">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier3">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">16</div>
</div>
```

My idea to solve this is to use `auto-fill` in the `grid-template-columns` property, but does not address the separate rows.

**auto-fill behaviour:**

[image]

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 50px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tier1 {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
  /* grid-column-end: span 3; */

.tier2 {
  background-color: mediumorchid;
  /* grid-column-end: span 4; */
}

.tier3 {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  /* grid-column-end: span 6; */
}

.tier4 {
  background-color: mediumvioletred;
  /* grid-column-end: span 2; */
}



Code snippet of above:
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item tier1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier3">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier3">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">16</div>
</div>
```

Is such a behaviour possible with CSS Grid?

Comment: What browser(s) are you using?

Comment: @Michael_B Chrome Version 57.0.2976.0 canary (64-bit)

Comment: could you make snippets here instead 2 links ? it is not handy at all to help you ....

Comment: @GCyrillus done

Answer (score 1):

i guess you can increase col numbers and span values so it can be also divided by 7.

you can also use `margin` instead  `grid-gap: 10px;`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(84, 1fr [col]);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 60px [row]);
 
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin:5px
}

.tier1 {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  grid-column-end: span 21;
}

.tier2 {
  background-color: mediumorchid;
  grid-column-end: span 28;
}

.tier3 {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  grid-column-end: span 42;
}

.tier4 {
  background-color: mediumvioletred;
  grid-column-end: span 12;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item tier1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier3">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier3">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">16</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are focusing on **CSS Grids**. But when I read:

> I want each of them to be *evenly spaced so that they take up all the
>   available space.*

That sounds to me like *CSS Flexbox* would be a perfect tool for the job.

Here is an alternative solution with **CSS Flexbox**:

```css
.grid-container {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 460px;
}

.grid-item {
display: block;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-align: center;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 9px;
margin: 4px;
}

.tier1 {
flex: 1 1 calc((100% - (2 * 4px * 4)) / 4); /* 4 blocks */
background-color: mediumseagreen;
}

.tier2 {
flex: 1 1 calc((100% - (2 * 4px * 3)) / 3); /* 3 blocks */
background-color: mediumorchid;
}

.tier3 {
flex: 1 1 calc((100% - (2 * 4px * 2)) / 2); /* 2 blocks */
background-color: mediumpurple;
}

.tier4 {
flex: 1 1 calc((100% - (2 * 4px * 7)) / 7); /* 7 blocks */
background-color: mediumvioletred;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item tier1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier1">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier2">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier3">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier3">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item tier4">16</div>
</div>
```